# Promote site collections as extranet sites in SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, intranet, extranet

I have a single web application which should be used by internals and external partners.

Some sites should be available for externals, some not and therefore I have created managed paths:

```
https://project.company.com/int
https://project.company.com/ext
```

I want to make all site collections on ext path to be available from outside.

Is it possible and if that's correct how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this. Here are some things you will need:

1. Your web application will need to have multiple authentication enabled: Windows for internal users, forms-based authentication (FBA) for external users.
2. You will need a site-collection feature that provides external user membership functionality and security policies that you can enable on your site collections in your ext managed path.
3. A forms-based authentication page that is friendly for both internal and external users.
4. A firewall/proxy that supports managed path routing (like Sophos UTM), assuming you only want to allow Internet traffic to the ext managed path.

Comment: Unfortunately paid for 3rd party services are off topic for this site.